# Как принять картинку и json в методе контроллера Spring-MVC

Tags: java, android, spring-mvc, okhttp

С кодом что ниже получаю 400 BadRequest

```
@ResponseBody
@RequestMapping(value = "/save",method = RequestMethod.POST)
public Object save(@RequestBody Banner banner,@RequestParam("file") MultipartFile file) {
    ... 
}
```

Класс `Banner` это простой java-объект с аксессорами.

Использую библиотеки:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
    <version>1.9.13</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
    <version>2.5.3</version>
</dependency>-->
```

чтобы они автоматом перевели приходящий `JSON` в экземпляр класса `Banner`

Отправляю `MultipartBody` из `okhttp` (android):

```
Thread threadt = new Thread(new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject();
        try {
            jsonObject.put("name","name");
            jsonObject.put("state","state");
            jsonObject.put("text","text");
            jsonObject.put("telNumber","telNumber");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        OkHttpClient client = SingletonOkHttp.getClient();

        RequestBody requestBody =null;
        RequestBody requestBody2 =null;
        try {
             requestBody = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("image/jpg"),new File(getRealPathFromUri(uriToSend)));
             requestBody2 = RequestBody.create(MediaType.parse("application/json"),jsonObject.toString());
        } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
        }

        MultipartBody.Builder builder = new MultipartBody.Builder()
            .addPart(requestBody)
            .addPart(requestBody2);

        MultipartBody  multipartBody = builder.build();
        Request request = new Request.Builder()
                .url("http://192.168.0.100:8080/save")
                .post(multipartBody)
                .build();

        try {
            Response response = client.newCall(request).execute();
            String str = response.body().string();
            if(str!=null){
                Log.e("str========>",str.toString());
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
});
```

Можно ли так сделать? Или сделать два запроса - один для json и второй для картинки?

Comment: Вы добавляете картинку в json, я правильно понял? А вы делаете преобразование в Base64? Или пихаете туда двоичные данные?

Comment: Я не знаю что такое OkHttpClient, если это обычный сокет, и у вас HTTP, вообще не понятно куда вы хотите прикреплять картинку... Насколько я знаю, протокол http не даёт возможность передавать 8 байтовые символы. Если вы хотите передать картинку через HTTP добавляйте атрибут в хидер и опять же, кодируйте картинку в Base64.

Comment: Спасибо.а контроллер ,он правильно написан?

Comment: >>а контроллер он правильно написан?<< Прошу прощения, не могу ответить на ваш вопрос.